# Tabla de verdad con 10 elementos Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, itertools

Quiero hacer una tabla de verdad con 10 elementos (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, a) y hacer todas las combinaciones posibles. Para ello estoy utilizando la libreria propia de Python [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

A continuación la forma que lo implemento:

```
import itertools

n = 10
table = list(itertools.product(['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['D'], ['E'], ['F'], ['G'], ['H'], ['I'], ['a'], repeat=n))

print(table)
```

Salida output:

```
[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'a', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'a', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'a', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'a', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'a', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'a', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'a', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'a', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'a', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'a')]
```

Si alguno sabe una mejor forma acepto cualquier sugerancia.

Comment: `table = list(itertools.product('ABCDEFGHIa', repeat=n))`

Comment: Ya lo intente y se me crashea toda la app

Comment: Bueno, si lo intentas con n=10 seguro que te vas a demorar un buen resto. Prueba con n=2 o 3.

Comment: ahi me funcionó, no hay posibilidad de que sea con n = 10 ?

Comment: Sería una secuencia de largo 10^10, si no me falla la combinatoria: 10.000.000.000 repeticiones.

Comment: El código espera a tener la lista completa de resultados. Es mejor iterar e ir recibiendo uno por uno los resultados: `for com  in itertools.product('ABCDEFGHIa', repeat=n):
    print(com)`

Comment: Si lo que buscas es generar todas las combinaciones posibles en poco tiempo, dudo que sea posible con 10 mil millones de items. Tendras que elegir una base de datos, o un lenguaje de programacion mas rapido (como c). Lo que le intentas pedir a Python con n=10 es como pedirle a una persona que lea la biblia en 3 minutos. No se crashea el programa, si no que aun trabaja.

Comment: Tienes razón, con n=2 me funciono mejor, voy a ir por ese lado